# TypeScript default import failing

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, typescript1.8

I am trying to setup a project and run tests with `mocha` with `mjackson/expect` library for assertion. My code to be tested is:

```
// inside src/lib/math.ts
export function sum(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}
```

and my test is as follows:

```
// inside src/tests/math.tests.ts
/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/mocha/mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/expect/expect.d.ts" />

import expect from 'expect';

import {sum} from '../lib/math';

describe('sum', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

I am able to compile the code with tsc using the following command:

`find src -name *.ts | xargs tsc --declaration --sourceMap --module commonjs --target es5 --listFiles --outDir .`

However when I run `mocha` from my project directory using the following command:

`mocha tests`

I see the following error in my tests:

`TypeError: expect_1.default is not a function`

When I open the compiled version of my `math.tests.ts`, I see the following line at the top of the transpiled code:

`var expect_1 = require('expect');`

This is fine and as expected. However, when I look inside the test where `expect` is called, I see the following line:

```
expect_1.default(math_1.sum(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
```

Now this line of code seems wrong. The `expect` library is bundled as an ES6 module and the `expect` function is a default export from the module.

However, TypeScript compiler has emitted code into my test where it attempts to access a `default` attribute on `expect_1` which is an import from the `expect` library. The `expect_1` reference itself is the default exported function I need in my tests and not `expect_1.default` which is invalid.

A point to note is, if I modified my `math.tests.ts` to import `expect` using the older `require` syntax. Everything works fine.

Please help me understand what I am missing.

P.S. I use TypeScript 1.8.2 with Node v4.3.1.

Comment: for me `const expect = require('expect');` works

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the expect namespace type is wrong in the npm package ([@types/expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/expect)) You can make small workaround to save type checking:

```
import * as _expect from 'expect';
const expect = _expect as any as typeof _expect.default;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked.  Is anyone working on a pull request on this?  Looks like the latest on github has already changed from what npm install can save.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the import statement from

```js
import expect from 'expect';
```

to

```js
import * as expect from 'expect';
```

i.e. get the full module instead of just the default export

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your expect package version does not match its declaration. I just installed one and found it does have a `default` entry:

```
exports['default'] = expect;
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

Comment: Yes I did see that too, but it still doesn't get imported correctly. I tried the same library with `babel`. It seems to use the `default` entry too and works perfectly. So what could be a solution to this?

Comment: Babel handles `default` entry differently, as I remember it would fall back to the entire exported module if no `default` entry found. But your code should work with current version of `expect`, try debugging it under JavaScript level and find out what's wrong.

Comment: Nothing seemed to work. Not sure if its a Typescript issue or an `expect` library issue. I've switched over to chai.js.